# IMG tag not working with HTML5 code and Phonegap

Tags: html, cordova

Hi. I want to show an image in my HTML5 code. Here's the code:

```
<div class="card"><img src="pics/back.png"/></div>
```

The image is not displayed, so I put the whole path like this:

```
<div class="card"><img src="file:///android_asset/www/pics/back.png"/></div>
```

But the problem persists. I'm using Phonegap also.

Any idea please?

Thank you so much.

Comment: check the path that image exist or not.

Answer (score 1):

I juste moved the image back.png under the folder "WWW" and it works fine 
here's the code :

```
  <div class="card"><img src="back.png"/></div>
```